# How do I let the user copy arbitrary text?

Tags: windows-phone-7, clipboard, user-experience

I have an app, where I generate text (about 500 characters), and I would like the user to have some means of copying that text for use outside of the application.

I don't want to use any capabilities for this app (like web, or contacts).

Here's what I've tried (and why it's failed)

- TextBox. IsReadOnly = true; SelectAll();

  - Can't SelectAll a read only text box
- Turn off read only, hide the SIP

  - Can't hide the SIP on a (non-read-only) TextBox that the user is interacting with (I want to enable the user to copy, so needs to interact with the control)
- allow edits, show sip, SelectAll()

  - The "copy" icon doesn't appear unless the user chose to select text
- On selection changed (actually changed), SelectAll()

  - The "copy" icon doesn't appear unless the user selected the text? The copy icon appears erratically, nothing I would call an acceptable user experience.

So at this point, I'm quite far from what I want in a user experience, and I still don't have anything that works. Any suggestions?

Some other possible ways to answer my question include:

- "How do I force the copy button to appear above text I programatically selected?"
- "How do I change the selection behavior of a tap in a text box?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I eventually got mostly working

```
    private void Export(StackPanel stacker)
    {
        var exportHeader = new TextBlock();
        exportHeader.Text = "Export";
        stacker.Children.Add(exportHeader);
        var exportBox = new TextBox();
        stacker.Children.Add(exportBox);
        //exportBox.IsReadOnly = true; // hides SIP, but causes an exception with SelectAll() (pre-Mango, I haven't tried on Mango yet)
        exportBox.FontSize = 1;
        exportBox.Text = textToExport;
        exportBox.GotFocus += new System.Windows.RoutedEventHandler((send, ev) =>
        {
            ((TextBox)send).SelectAll();
        });
        exportBox.Focus();
    }
```

Apparently, making the font size 1 makes the difference here, maybe because all of the text can appear on the screen at once? Who knows.

I accepted this answer, because no one else posted a better solution. I would appreciate a better solution. If you can get the SIP to go away, that would be awesome.

Comment: Pending any additional comments, I'll be accepting this answer. I don't like the solution, but it seems as if that's the best we've got.

Answer (score 0):

Afaik there are some limitations to the Windows Phone 7 Clipboard:

- Works only in TextBox and can only copy text upon users wish
- Text is only kept until device gets locked. If your device gets locked, the clipboard will be wiped clean

Even if you try [Clipboard.SetText Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597043%28v=vs.96%29.aspx), you will notice the SecurityException if you call this method without the users interaction. This is to keep the users data under control so that no rogue app can copy unrecognized Text.

But you could try Matt Laceys [WP7Clipboard](http://wp7clipboard.codeplex.com/). It saves the clipboard content inside an image and can even copy bitmaps.

Comment: So, yes, I understand those limitations, those aren't the limitations that are annoying me, I expect to put the text into a textbox, and allow the user to copy it easily. That's what I want. How do I make that easy for them? AFAICT, Matt Lacey's clipboard doesn't work in native apps, like email, web browsing, and text messaging, which doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try restyling the textbox as per http://mobileworld.appamundi.com/blogs/peterfoot/archive/2011/02/08/copyable-textblock-for-windows-phone.aspx

Comment: So, this copyable textblock is basically what I tried with my first bullet, the problem is that I need to be able to allow the user to easily copy all of the text, and there's a lot of it. I don't want the user to have to manually select the text (because there's a lot of it), I want the user to quickly copy the text.